# On calling the balanceOf(address user) function from an external contract on my existing contract, throws an error

Tags: solidity, erc-721

If I want my contract to call the functions of an external contract, we would have to create an interface of the external contract, and then we can call its functions. I have a mint function that checks if the minter owns any tokens from an external contract. The code below throws this error when I try to call it

> The called function should be payable if you send value, and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance

```
address public otherNFTContractAddress = 0x8A787dADB36fE6ABA8eD99dC135514e0e3019eb4;
OtherContractInterface public otherContract = OtherContractInterface(address(otherNFTContractAddress));

function freeMint(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        if ( IERC721(otherNFTContractAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1) {
            ........
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this function ? please share the code. And also please show the complete code of the freemint function

Comment: If you can share whole func and relative parameters of contract, that can deploy and test it

Comment: It looks like you are sending eth to the function, try not doing that. On another note, otherNFTContractAddress is already an address, no need to cast it.